# ¿Como colocar las leyendas en una sola columna de una gráfica de torta y hacer responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, chart.js

Tengo una gráfica de torta en [**Chartjs**](https://www.chartjs.org/), cuando hay demasiados segmentos crea 2 columnas y me gustaría que haga una sola columna, y que se actualice al rehacer la gráfica, si es necesario colocar un **scrollbar**, pues se coloca, pero no encuentro como colocarlo. También redimensionar con respecto a la resolución en la que se cargue la gráfica.

Acá el código en [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6u31qv7p/4/show) (tiene mas de 30k de letras y **esSO** no me lo permite).

- Esto en una pantalla grande

[image: Esto en una pantalla grande]

- Si lo abro en una pantalla mas pequeña se crean 2 columnas

[image: Si lo abro en una pantalla mas pequeña se crean 2 columnas]

- Y si lo abro en una pantalla aun mas pequeña no se ve la gráfica por las leyendas

[image: Y si lo abro en una pantalla aun mas pequeña no se ve la gráfica por las leyendas]

**Actualización 1**:
Con la ayuda del usuario **alcamalama** logre hacer lo siguiente: [***enlace***](https://jsfiddle.net/h0cf1smz/), pero no logro hacer que en las leyendas tome la acción como la toma en su estado normal (eliminar segmentos de la torta y rehacerla).

El problema en mi web es que no se colocan los colores y no entiendo el ¿Por que?.

[image: error]

Answer (score 13):

En tu [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4Luftgn5/1/) encontré los siguientes errores:

- **Referencia a propiedad no definida**: En la línea `2021` se establece que `var ci = e.view.grafica_pie;`, lo que provoca que `ci` sea `undefined`.

  La solución es simplemente usar la variable global `grafica_pie`;
- **Indice a propiedad inexistente**: En la línea `2023` se establece que `var curr = ci.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].data[index];`, lo que al entrar a un sub-gráfico resulta en error, dado que `._meta[0]` no siempre existe.

  La solución es usar [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys) sobre `._meta` para obtener un arreglo con las propiedades de dicho objeto y pedir la primera, es decir, `Object.keys(grafica_pie.data.datasets[0]._meta)[0]`
- **Markup inválido**: En la linea `13` del `HTML` faltaba cerrar un `div`.
- **Asignación de eventos**: En la linea `2018`, se establece `$("#js-legend > ul > li")` lo que provoca que al regenerar el menú de leyendas, no funcione mas.

  La solución es usar [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), es decir, `$("#js-legend").on("click", 'ul > li',function(e){`

[**Solución completa**](https://jsfiddle.net/4Luftgn5/2/)

> **NOTA:** **El snippet debajo no esta completo**, la variable `datos` ha sido modificada porque es demasiado larga y *el cuerpo de las respuesta esta limitado a 30000 caracteres*.

#### Solución:

```js
let datos = [{
    "id": 20,
    "nombre": "Infusiones",
    "id_padre": 0,
    "menu": [{
        "id": 188,
        "nombre": "Te",
        "precio": 5,
        "id_padre": 20,
        "cantidad": "4",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 189,
        "nombre": "Anis",
        "precio": 5,
        "id_padre": 20,
        "cantidad": "5",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 190,
        "nombre": "Manzanila",
        "precio": 5,
        "id_padre": 20,
        "cantidad": "4",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 191,
        "nombre": "Hierba luisa",
        "precio": 5,
        "id_padre": 20,
        "cantidad": "3",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 192,
        "nombre": "Cafe americano",
        "precio": 8,
        "id_padre": 20,
        "cantidad": "1",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 193,
        "nombre": "Cafe capuccion",
        "precio": 9,
        "id_padre": 20,
        "cantidad": "1",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      }
    ],
    "cantidad": 18,
    "precio": 37,
    "promedio_ta": 0,
    "promedio_tp": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "nombre": "Tiraditos",
    "id_padre": 0,
    "menu": [{
        "id": 83,
        "nombre": "Tiradito de pescado",
        "precio": 36,
        "id_padre": 28,
        "cantidad": "12",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 84,
        "nombre": "Tiradito de Gallese a dos tiempos",
        "precio": 38,
        "id_padre": 28,
        "cantidad": "7",
        "promedio_ta": 0.86,
        "promedio_tp": 0.86
      },
      {
        "id": 85,
        "nombre": "Tiradito mixto",
        "precio": 38,
        "id_padre": 28,
        "cantidad": "5",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      }
    ],
    "cantidad": 24,
    "precio": 112,
    "promedio_ta": 0.86,
    "promedio_tp": 0.86
  },
  {
    "id": 54,
    "nombre": "Recomendacion del Chef",
    "id_padre": 0,
    "menu": [{
        "id": 315,
        "nombre": "corvina",
        "precio": 54,
        "id_padre": 54,
        "cantidad": "40",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 446,
        "nombre": "Parihuela De Cabrilla",
        "precio": 36,
        "id_padre": 54,
        "cantidad": null,
        "promedio_ta": null,
        "promedio_tp": null
      },
      {
        "id": 447,
        "nombre": "Sudado de Cabrilla",
        "precio": 36,
        "id_padre": 54,
        "cantidad": null,
        "promedio_ta": null,
        "promedio_tp": null
      },
      {
        "id": 448,
        "nombre": "Cabrilla Frita",
        "precio": 30,
        "id_padre": 54,
        "cantidad": null,
        "promedio_ta": null,
        "promedio_tp": null
      },
      {
        "id": 449,
        "nombre": "Cabrilla A Lo Macho",
        "precio": 36,
        "id_padre": 54,
        "cantidad": null,
        "promedio_ta": null,
        "promedio_tp": null
      }
    ],
    "cantidad": 40,
    "precio": 192,
    "promedio_ta": 0,
    "promedio_tp": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 44,
    "nombre": "Criollo",
    "id_padre": 0,
    "menu": [{
        "id": 117,
        "nombre": "Lomo fino saltado",
        "precio": 42,
        "id_padre": 44,
        "cantidad": "10",
        "promedio_ta": 2.7,
        "promedio_tp": 2.3
      },
      {
        "id": 118,
        "nombre": "Arroz chaufa de pollo",
        "precio": 26,
        "id_padre": 44,
        "cantidad": "21",
        "promedio_ta": 0.71,
        "promedio_tp": 0.48
      },
      {
        "id": 120,
        "nombre": "Tacu tacu con lomo fino saltado",
        "precio": 42,
        "id_padre": 44,
        "cantidad": "11",
        "promedio_ta": 1.64,
        "promedio_tp": 1.09
      },
      {
        "id": 121,
        "nombre": "Tacu tacu con pollo a la plancha",
        "precio": 30,
        "id_padre": 44,
        "cantidad": "5",
        "promedio_ta": 3.4,
        "promedio_tp": 2.2
      },
      {
        "id": 124,
        "nombre": "Pollo a la plancha con papas fritas y ensalada",
        "precio": 26,
        "id_padre": 44,
        "cantidad": "37",
        "promedio_ta": 1.65,
        "promedio_tp": 1.27
      },
      {
        "id": 125,
        "nombre": "Tacu tacu con pescado a la plancha",
        "precio": 36,
        "id_padre": 44,
        "cantidad": "8",
        "promedio_ta": 1.5,
        "promedio_tp": 0.13
      },
      {
        "id": 126,
        "nombre": "Parrilla marina",
        "precio": 48,
        "id_padre": 44,
        "cantidad": "2",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 127,
        "nombre": "Brochetas de pescado",
        "precio": 48,
        "id_padre": 44,
        "cantidad": "2",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 128,
        "nombre": "Milanesa de pollo y/o pescado",
        "precio": 36,
        "id_padre": 44,
        "cantidad": "6",
        "promedio_ta": 5.33,
        "promedio_tp": 3.83
      },
      {
        "id": 864,
        "nombre": "milanesa de pollo  personal",
        "precio": 36,
        "id_padre": 44,
        "cantidad": null,
        "promedio_ta": null,
        "promedio_tp": null
      },
      {
        "id": 865,
        "nombre": "milanesa de pescado personal",
        "precio": 36,
        "id_padre": 44,
        "cantidad": null,
        "promedio_ta": null,
        "promedio_tp": null
      }
    ],
    "cantidad": 102,
    "precio": 406,
    "promedio_ta": 16.93,
    "promedio_tp": 11.3
  },
  {
    "id": 43,
    "nombre": "Parihuelas",
    "id_padre": 0,
    "menu": [{
        "id": 114,
        "nombre": "parihuela de pescado mixto",
        "precio": 34,
        "id_padre": 43,
        "cantidad": "69",
        "promedio_ta": 1.49,
        "promedio_tp": 0.65
      },
      {
        "id": 115,
        "nombre": "parihuela de chita",
        "precio": 56,
        "id_padre": 43,
        "cantidad": "13",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 116,
        "nombre": "Parihuela de tramboyo",
        "precio": 46,
        "id_padre": 43,
        "cantidad": "19",
        "promedio_ta": 1.89,
        "promedio_tp": 1.11
      },
      {
        "id": 868,
        "nombre": "parihuela tramboyo natural",
        "precio": 40,
        "id_padre": 43,
        "cantidad": "1",
        "promedio_ta": 21,
        "promedio_tp": 20
      }
    ],
    "cantidad": 102,
    "precio": 176,
    "promedio_ta": 24.38,
    "promedio_tp": 21.76
  },
  {
    "id": 46,
    "nombre": "Guarniciones",
    "id_padre": 0,
    "menu": [{
        "id": 134,
        "nombre": "Arroz blanco",
        "precio": 6,
        "id_padre": 46,
        "cantidad": "80",
        "promedio_ta": 0.61,
        "promedio_tp": 0.25
      },
      {
        "id": 135,
        "nombre": "Camote",
        "precio": 6,
        "id_padre": 46,
        "cantidad": "18",
        "promedio_ta": 0.17,
        "promedio_tp": 0.11
      },
      {
        "id": 136,
        "nombre": "Cancha",
        "precio": 6,
        "id_padre": 46,
        "cantidad": "8",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 137,
        "nombre": "Chifle",
        "precio": 6,
        "id_padre": 46,
        "cantidad": "7",
        "promedio_ta": 0.29,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 138,
        "nombre": "Yucas fritas",
        "precio": 6,
        "id_padre": 46,
        "cantidad": "13",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 139,
        "nombre": "Papas fritas",
        "precio": 6,
        "id_padre": 46,
        "cantidad": "4",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 862,
        "nombre": "yucas  sancochadas",
        "precio": 6,
        "id_padre": 46,
        "cantidad": "1",
        "promedio_ta": 5,
        "promedio_tp": 4
      }
    ],
    "cantidad": 131,
    "precio": 42,
    "promedio_ta": 6.07,
    "promedio_tp": 4.36
  },
  {
    "id": 45,
    "nombre": "Platos Kids",
    "id_padre": 0,
    "menu": [{
        "id": 129,
        "nombre": "Chicharron de pescado kids",
        "precio": 20,
        "id_padre": 45,
        "cantidad": "56",
        "promedio_ta": 0.46,
        "promedio_tp": 0.29
      },
      {
        "id": 130,
        "nombre": "Cebiche de pescado kids",
        "precio": 20,
        "id_padre": 45,
        "cantidad": "53",
        "promedio_ta": 0.64,
        "promedio_tp": 0.42
      },
      {
        "id": 131,
        "nombre": "Chicharron de pollo kids",
        "precio": 20,
        "id_padre": 45,
        "cantidad": "19",
        "promedio_ta": 0.37,
        "promedio_tp": 0.21
      },
      {
        "id": 132,
        "nombre": "Pechuga de pollo baby",
        "precio": 20,
        "id_padre": 45,
        "cantidad": "5",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 133,
        "nombre": "Milanesa de pollo kids",
        "precio": 20,
        "id_padre": 45,
        "cantidad": "7",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 436,
        "nombre": "Milanesa de pescado kids",
        "precio": 20,
        "id_padre": 45,
        "cantidad": "10",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 21,
        "nombre": "Nuestra Barra",
        "id_padre": 45,
        "menu": [{
            "id": 194,
            "nombre": "Pisco sour",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "44",
            "promedio_ta": 0.09,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 196,
            "nombre": "Maracuya sour",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "21",
            "promedio_ta": 2.05,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 197,
            "nombre": "Chilcano de pisco",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "13",
            "promedio_ta": 0,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 198,
            "nombre": "Machupicchu",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "11",
            "promedio_ta": 0,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 199,
            "nombre": "Chilcano de maracuya",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "13",
            "promedio_ta": 0.15,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 200,
            "nombre": "pina colada",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "6",
            "promedio_ta": 1,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 201,
            "nombre": "Mojito",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "4",
            "promedio_ta": 0,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 202,
            "nombre": "Cuba libre",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "5",
            "promedio_ta": 0,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 203,
            "nombre": "Daiquiri de durazno",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "5",
            "promedio_ta": 0,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 204,
            "nombre": "Algarrobina",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "8",
            "promedio_ta": 0,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 205,
            "nombre": "Amor en llamas",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "4",
            "promedio_ta": 0,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 206,
            "nombre": "Esmeralda",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "4",
            "promedio_ta": 0,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 207,
            "nombre": "Bon ami",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "4",
            "promedio_ta": 0,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 208,
            "nombre": "Peru libre",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "4",
            "promedio_ta": 0,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 209,
            "nombre": "Laguna azul",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "5",
            "promedio_ta": 0,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 210,
            "nombre": "Sangria especial",
            "precio": 24,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "5",
            "promedio_ta": 0,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 211,
            "nombre": "Vino ocucaje jarra",
            "precio": 24,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "4",
            "promedio_ta": 0,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          },
          {
            "id": 316,
            "nombre": "Happy hour 2 x 1",
            "precio": 18,
            "id_padre": 21,
            "cantidad": "8",
            "promedio_ta": 0,
            "promedio_tp": 0
          }
        ],
        "cantidad": 168,
        "precio": 336,
        "promedio_ta": 3.29,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      }
    ],
    "cantidad": 150,
    "precio": 120,
    "promedio_ta": 1.47,
    "promedio_tp": 0.92
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "nombre": "Pescados",
    "id_padre": 0,
    "menu": [{
        "id": 61,
        "nombre": "Pescado a la plancha",
        "precio": 30,
        "id_padre": 23,
        "cantidad": "100",
        "promedio_ta": 1.38,
        "promedio_tp": 1.08
      },
      {
        "id": 62,
        "nombre": "Chita frita",
        "precio": 52,
        "id_padre": 23,
        "cantidad": "18",
        "promedio_ta": 0.94,
        "promedio_tp": 0.67
      },
      {
        "id": 63,
        "nombre": "Pescado al ajo (filete)",
        "precio": 32,
        "id_padre": 23,
        "cantidad": "20",
        "promedio_ta": 0.7,
        "promedio_tp": 0.6
      },
      {
        "id": 86,
        "nombre": "Pescado frito(Filete)",
        "precio": 28,
        "id_padre": 23,
        "cantidad": "56",
        "promedio_ta": 0.95,
        "promedio_tp": 0.39
      },
      {
        "id": 87,
        "nombre": "Pescado a lo macho(filete)",
        "precio": 36,
        "id_padre": 23,
        "cantidad": "11",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 88,
        "nombre": "Chita a lo macho(500gr) o segun peso",
        "precio": 56,
        "id_padre": 23,
        "cantidad": "6",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 89,
        "nombre": "Chita al ajo",
        "precio": 54,
        "id_padre": 23,
        "cantidad": "10",
        "promedio_ta": 0,
        "promedio_tp": 0
      }
    ],
    "cantidad": 221,
    "precio": 288,
    "promedio_ta": 3.97,
    "promedio_tp": 2.74
  }
];

var graphColors = [];
var graphOutlines = [];
var hoverColor = [];

var internalDataLength = datos.length;
i = 0;
while (i <= internalDataLength) {
  var randomR = Math.floor((Math.random() * 130) + 100);
  var randomG = Math.floor((Math.random() * 130) + 100);
  var randomB = Math.floor((Math.random() * 130) + 100);

  var graphBackground = "rgb(" +
    randomR + ", " +
    randomG + ", " +
    randomB + ")";
  graphColors.push(graphBackground);

  var graphOutline = "rgb(" +
    (randomR - 80) + ", " +
    (randomG - 80) + ", " +
    (randomB - 80) + ")";
  graphOutlines.push(graphOutline);

  var hoverColors = "rgb(" +
    (randomR + 25) + ", " +
    (randomG + 25) + ", " +
    (randomB + 25) + ")";
  hoverColor.push(hoverColors);

  i++;
};

let array_cantidad_ventas_pie = [];
let grafica_pie = null;
let array_padre_f = [];

var grafica_cantidad_ventas_pie = function(datos) {
  //console.log('datos->',datos);
  if ((datos['menu']) || (datos['menu'] != 'undefined')) {
    datos = datos.sort(function(a, b) {
      return parseFloat(a['cantidad']) - parseFloat(b['cantidad']);
    });
    let labels = [];
    let data = [];
    let datalabels = [];
    $.each(datos, function(index, value) {
      labels.push(value['nombre']);
      data.push(value['cantidad']);
      datalabels.push(value);
    });
    if (grafica_pie) {
      grafica_pie.destroy();
    }

    let chart_cv = document.getElementById("chart_cant_ventas");
    grafica_pie = new Chart(chart_cv, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
          label: "Population (millions)",
          data: data,
          datalabels: datalabels,
          backgroundColor: graphColors,
          hoverBackgroundColor: hoverColor,
          borderColor: graphOutlines,
        }]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: false,
        legend: false,
        legendCallback: function(grafica_pie) {
          var ul = document.createElement('ul');
          ul.className = "pie-legend";
          grafica_pie.data.labels.forEach(function(label, index) {
            ul.innerHTML += "<li><span style='background-color: " + grafica_pie.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[index] + "; border-color: " + grafica_pie.data.datasets[0].borderColor[index] + "; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;'></span>" + label + "</li>"; // ^ ES6 Template String
          });

          return ul.outerHTML;
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Cantidad de ventas por producto',
        },
        events: ['mousemove', 'mouseout', 'click', 'touchstart', 'touchmove', 'mouseup'],
        onClick: function(e, dataAtClick) {
          if (dataAtClick != null && dataAtClick.length > 0) {
            var index = dataAtClick[0]["_index"];
            var objData = this.data.datasets[0].datalabels[index];

            var e = e || window.event;
            var btnCode;

            if ('object' === typeof e) {
              btnCode = e.button;

              switch (btnCode) {
                case 0:
                  if (objData['menu']) {
                    grafica_cantidad_ventas_pie(objData['menu']);
                  }
                  break;

                case 1:
                  grafica_cantidad_ventas_pie(array_padre_f);
                  break;

                case 2:
                  if (objData['id_padre'] !== 0) {
                    buscarPadres(array_cantidad_ventas_pie, objData['id_padre'], array_cantidad_ventas_pie);
                    grafica_cantidad_ventas_pie(array_padre_f);
                  }
                  break;

                default:
                  grafica_cantidad_ventas_pie(array_padre_f);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
    document.getElementById('js-legend').innerHTML = grafica_pie.generateLegend();
  }
}

function buscarPadres(array, id, array_padre) {
  $.each(array, function(key, value) {
    if (value['id'] == id) {
      array_padre_f = array_padre;
      return false;
    } else {
      if (value['menu']) {
        buscarPadres(value['menu'], id, value['menu']);
      }
    }
  });
}

array_cantidad_ventas_pie = datos;
grafica_cantidad_ventas_pie(array_cantidad_ventas_pie);

$("#js-legend").on("click", 'ul > li', function(e) {
  var index = $(this).index();
  $(this).toggleClass("strike");

  var metas = Object.keys(grafica_pie.data.datasets[0]._meta);
  var curr = grafica_pie.data.datasets[0]._meta[metas[0]].data[index];
  curr.hidden = !curr.hidden
  grafica_pie.update();
});
```

```css
.chart-legend li span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.chart-legend {
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.chart-legend li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through !important;
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<section class="graficas">
  <div class="float-left">
    <div class="float-left" style="width:70%">
      <canvas id="chart_cant_ventas" width="500" height="300" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="float-left" style="width:30%">
      <div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: He visto la solucion que propones y van mis **`+1`** (buena respuesta), pero seria bueno que si colocaras el snippet, que tal si a la variable `datos` le reduces la cantidad de registro, de esta forma podras colocar el codigo y no queda en un enlace externo que con el tiempo se puede perder.

Comment: Si uso el **legendCallback** no me muestra los colores en las leyendas [**capture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgMub.png). Si le elimino el **legendCallback** lo muestra de [**esta manera**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK3vd.png).

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa, muy acertada tu observación, gracias! He actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: @PabloContreras, será que has olvidado copiar los estilos que afectan a los `span` dentro? Me refiero puntualmente al estilo `.chart-legend li span`

Answer (score 3):

Según explican en la documentación de **Chart.js** el tamaño de renderización del *canvas* donde se muestra la gráfica no se puede modificar por medio de atributos relativos, por ello indican que lo correcto es insertar el *canvas* en un `div` cuya posición y tamaño sean relativos a la resolución de la pantalla:

`<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:80vw">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>`

En tu caso le he echado un vistazo al código y siguiendo estas instrucciones he añadido un `div` conteniendo tu gráfica, además he necesitado añadir la siguiente línea de código en las opciones de la gráfica: `maintainAspectRatio: false`

Con esta solución se muestra la gráfica siempre con el mismo tamaño independientemente de la resolución de la pantalla, por lo que si esta es muy pequeña aparecerá tanto un scroll vertical como horizontal, no se si esto será un inconveniente pero no he conseguido que la gráfica reduzca su tamaño sin variar el número de columnas.

Link con el código:
https://jsfiddle.net/93f6r2nc/

Enlaces:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html

Comment: Gracias por tu colaboración, interesante saber lo del responsive, esta bien, quedo claro eso.
Pero las leyendas las quiero en una sola columna con un scroll, lo único que se me ocurre es colocarlas en un div, pero no se como tomar ese evento.

Comment: Ya entiendo, pensaba que te referías a que siempre se mostrara en una sola columna la leyenda independientemente del tamaño de la gráfica. Pensaré una solución, aunque eso complica notablemente las cosas ya que la leyenda la dibuja el propio canvas y no se si será posible acceder a ella.

Comment: Una pregunta muy similar a la tuya está resuelta en este link por si le quieres echar un vistazo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229626/how-to-fix-chart-legends-width-height-with-overflow-scroll-in-chartjs

Comment: No logro llevarlo al ejemplo de mi código, actualice mi pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que puedes hacer es usar la función `legendCallback` de `chartJS`, lo que hace es crear tus `legends` introduciendo `html`, osea que los puedes personalizar a tu gusto y agregarles css, la ventaja de esto es que tu decides donde agregar tus `legends`, en el caso de mi ejemplo, puse un `div` junto con el `canvas` dentro de ese `div` introduje los `legends` y deje el `canvas` solo con la gráfica.

Aquí esta mi ejemplo tomado en base al tuyo, espero sea lo que necesitas:

https://jsfiddle.net/vd3m8r6w/1/

(Introduje un fiddle por que el código sobre pasa las lineas permitidas en el snipped).

Comment: ¿Como podría mantener la acción de la leyenda? La que quita uno de los segmentos al presionar alguno de los items.

Comment: Una duda sobre ese evento de click, cuando presionas alguna leyenda, te debe de cargar los hijos de ese padre? o que deberia de hacer?

Comment: No, la misma acción de la leyenda del chartjs original, eliminar los segmentos.

Comment: Edité mi fiddle, eso es lo que buscas?